# Implement Websockets into my Tomcat Servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, websocket

Iam trying to use websockets in my already working servlet. My Problem is that i used the "writer" class to post HTML onto the broswer but I cant find a similar class for WebSockets.

My servlet looks like this:

```
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private List<ISort> sortierListe = new ArrayList<ISort>();
private File file1;
private PrintWriter writer2;
private boolean sortFinished;
boolean bSubmitForFilenamePressedCopy;
BufferedReader in;
// private String sEingabe;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public TestServlet() {
    super();    
    this.initSortierverfahren();
}

private void initSortierverfahren() {
    sortierListe.add(new BubbleSort());
    sortierListe.add(new QuickSort());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

[...]

PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer2 = writer;
    writer.println("<html>");
    writer.println("<head><title>Text Sortieren!</title>");
    writer.println("</head>");

    writer.println("<body marginwidth='40' leftmargin='40' bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>");

    writer.println("<table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' height='100%' width='57%' border='0' cellpadding=10>");
    writer.println("<tr height='10%'>");
    writer.println("
[...]
```

The code is too long to post everything, but the Servlet basicly creates a form where I can enter a path to a .txt file. The txt file will then be sorted by either bubblesort or quicksort.

My Question is: How can I use this code in a WebSocket without rewriting everything in javascript? Just some basic help for the start would help me alot I think. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First, If you want to work with websockets from tomcat, you should extend from corresponding base class WebSocketServlet.

Second, I don't think that it's worth using websocket in your case. Websockets are good for applications which require real-time interactions. Yours obviously doesn't require it.

If you still want to do this, just create some simple javascript which will write your html to the body. Something along lines with:

```
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { 
  document.body.innerHtml += evt.data
};
```

But as I said, I see no use in such a code.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I need to use WebSockets because i have to do it as a task to learn more about them. (In the end I want a loading spinner during my sorting process) Now i got thejavascritp you posted but how do i send the HTML data from the server to the page? In my servlet i used writer.println but that doesnt work anymore. And with outbound.writeTextData I can only send char data? Iam very new to java by the way so sorry for the many questions.

Comment: @user1677568 you should send HTML as char data, i.e. convert a string to CharBuffer. You can find an example here:  http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/05/01/how-apache-tomcat-implemented-websocket

Answer (score 0):

Before you make move from normal servlet to websocket there are few things keep in mind.

1. Use latest apache tomcat version. Plder version won't support websockets. (I used version 7.0.42 in my case)
2. You can't simply replace your Servlet with WebSocket. Purpose of both is totally different. Google it out for more details.

This **[sample code for WebSocket](https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774)** provides server side as well as client side sample code. You should refer it to get started with.